# Android (FragmentActivity и TabHost)

Tags: android-sdk, android

Здравствуйте, уважаемые хешкодовцы!

Есть вот такая задача, в которой нужна ваша помощь: существует FragmentActivity, у него в свою очередь 3 Fragment. На первом фрагменте находится текстовое поле EditText. Сверху находятся три вкладки соответственно (TabHost).

Собственно проблема в следующем, если нажать одновременно на Edit Text  и любой из Tab, то получаю следующее, на открывшемся Tab все элементы сдвинуты и отображается клавиатура. Это при учете того, что на открывшемся Tab вообще нет элементов EditText.

Рискну предположить, что при нажатии срабатывает сразу два события (переключение вкладок и открытие клавиатуры), причем переключение вкладок происходит раньше чем открывается клавиатура,  т.е. на момент открытия не получается скрыть клавиатуру, она игнорирует все попытки в onStart, onAttach, onCreate, setUserVisibleHint

Не знаю как решить проблему.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Честно говоря, я боюсь даже представить, зачем нормальному пользователю может понадобиться нажимать одновременно на 2 виджета.

Comment: Дело не в нормальности пользователя, а в том что софт тестит  очень хороший тестировщик. Его задача найти самые немыслемые баги :) А моя задача их исправить....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем проблема решилась.

Решение нашлось вот здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128415/android-viewpager-show-soft-keyboard-in-the-wrong-place

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) 
{
    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
    {
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0)
        {
            // Hide the keyboard.
            ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .hideSoftInputFromWindow(mViewPager.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну только конкретно в моем случае поменял mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0 на mViewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0